# Topshelf - How do I modify the Password command line argument before installing the service

Tags: c#, topshelf

I want to install my service via the command line and by specifying an encrypted password, for example

```
MyService.exe install -servicename "MyService" -username "MyPC\MyServiceUser" -password "0D689361D6D7DC4E"
```

I've tried to modify the password argument in the constructor

```cs
public class MyService: ServiceControl
{
  public static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    DecodePasswords(args);
    var host = HostFactory.New(x =>
    {
      x.Service<MyService>(hostSettings => new MyService(hostSettings));
    }); 
    return OkStatuses.Contains(exitCode) ? 0 : (int)exitCode;
  }

  private static bool IsInstalling(string[] args)
  {
      return (args.Length > 2) && (args[0].ToUpper() == "INSTALL");
  }
 
  private static void DecodePasswords(string[] args)
  {
      if (IsInstalling(args))
      {
          var encryptedPassword = string.Empty;
          for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
          {
              var arg = args[i].Trim().ToUpper();
              if (arg == "-PASSWORD" && ((i + 1 < args.Length)))
              {
                  encryptedPassword = args[i + 1];
                  try
                  {
                      args[i + 1] = DecodePassword(encryptedPassword);
                      Console.WriteLine(args[i + 1]); //TODO TEMP
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                      //ignore
                      break;
                  }
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I've checked the arguments and decoded password and they are correct, but when I start the service the following error occurs:

> The MyService service failed to start due to the following error:  The
> service did not start due to a log-on failure.
>
> The MyService service was unable to log on as .\MyServiceUser with the currently
> configured password due to the following error:  The username or
> password is incorrect.

I've tried *BeforeInstall* but *HostSettings* but contains the *ServiceName* etc. but not the Password.

Comment: Did you get this sorted by a conversation on the mailing list?

Comment: I've quickly tried but did not have time again to resolve.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/topshelf-discuss/4iBCSS0WW4c
https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/pull/222